# How add extra blockdevices to machineset in OKD4.4

Tags: amazon-web-services, okd

I have created a machineset YAML file with 2 EBS disks. Here is a snip of the YAML file:

```
apiVersion: awsproviderconfig.openshift.io/v1beta1
      blockDevices:
        - ebs:
            iops: 0
            volumeSize: 120
            volumeType: gp2
        - ebs: 
            iops: 0
            volumeSize: 2048
            volumeType: gp2
```

When I run `oc create -f machineset.yaml` the instance is created in AWS but without an extra disk. So my question is: how can I add an extra disk to my machineset YAML file.